# New deb application does not appear in dash

Tags: unity, unity-dash, gdebi

I've had this problem in 14.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS. After installing a new application (Viber, e.g.) via Gdebi, Synaptic or Ubuntu software, the application does not appear in Unity dash (or classic menu indicator) until I reboot.

It's quite annoying, is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: Try running `updatedb` command in terminal and then check to see if the app shows up.

Comment: Nope, still no effect.